# Formato Condicional Excel

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, formularios, vba

Buen día, estoy creando un spreadsheet con un formulario para poder documentar el status de una orden. Dependiendo del status, las celdas de la A a la N tienen que cambiar de color, adicionalmente para ciertos status como por ejemplo "CI ERROR/TICKET", el color de la letra tiene que cambiar a color blanco y negrita. Ya pude lograr cambiar el color en el rango de celdas mencionado (A,N), lo que no puedo hacer es cambiar el color y estilo de la fuente en el mismo código. Adicionalmente estoy tratando de hacer un checklist en las casillas (O,Z) y deberia poder cambiar el color de cada celda dependiendo de valor: "Y", "NA" y "P". Honestamente llegue al final de mis capacidades, esto es lo que tengo de codigo en los atributos de la hoja de Excel:

```
Option Explicit Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("H")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim trgt As Range
    For Each trgt In Intersect(Target, Columns("H"))
        Select Case LCase(trgt.Value2)
        Case "2 day process"
                Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                Case "advisor"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "back in"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
                Case "ci error/ticket"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                Case "completed"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                Case "completed/backup"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 51
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                Case "credentialing"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 49
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                Case "credit"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
                Case "duplicate"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                Case "held"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "master data"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "name change"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "ofr"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Case "op consultant"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "post process"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 32
                Case "pps"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "react acct"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case "rejected"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                Case "transferred"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                Case "zpnd"
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Case Else
                    Cells(trgt.Row, "A").Resize(1, 14).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End Select
    Next trgt
End If bm_Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente para el cambio de colores de una celda según su contenido utilizaría el `formato condicional`, te permite utilizar condicionales igualmente y si se cumple se aplica el formato fuente que le indiques en dicha línea.

Para copiar dicho "codigo" de formato condicional a otra celda que comparta las mismas condiciones se utiliza la opcion `copiar formato` de Excel.

De esta forma te resultará más portable el código, además de poder aplicarlo a muchas celdas diferentes sin tener que cambiar el código VBS que hay debajo.

https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Usar-un-f%C3%B3rmula-para-aplicar-formato-condicional-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 1):

Para dar respuesta a este tema se puede hacer lo siguiente:

Para el estilo de la fuente `.Font.Bold = True`

Para el color de la fuente `.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)` color Blanco

Para el color de la celda `.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

en este [link](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/es/) se encuentran los parámetros RGB para los colores.

Por otro lado recomiendo "factorizar" `Cells(trgt.row, "A").Resize(1, 14)` usando `with` hace que sea mas legible el código.

```
With Cells(trgt.row, "A").Resize(1, 14)
    Select Case LCase(trgt.Value2)
        Case "2 day process"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        Case "advisor"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        Case "back in"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        Case "ci error/ticket"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    ...
End With
```